# Extract string with regex in C#

Tags: c#, regex

I have this string in C#: "/19/Ora01" and i want to exctract "Ora01"

I have tried with no success:

```
var pattern = @"^(Ora[0-9]{2})$";

var match = Regex.Match(args.Path, pattern);

var hour = match.Groups[0].Value;
```

What I'm doing wrong?

What about to exctract two other strings, one with 19, the other with Ora01?

Comment: ([A-Z])\w+ will give you Ora01

Comment: `^` means "start of string" and `"$" means "end of string. YOu asked for something that contains only `Ora` followed by two digits. Remove `^` at least. You don't need grouping either. `Ora[0-9]{2}` should work

Comment: Try `@"/(\d+)/(Ora\d+)"` and then `match.Group[1].Value` and `match.Group[2].Value`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`^` means "start of string" and "$" means "end of string. You asked for something that contains only `Ora` followed by two digits. Remove ^ at least. You don't need grouping either. `Ora[0-9]{2}` should work :

```
var pattern = @"Ora[0-9]{2}";

var match = Regex.Match("/19/Ora01", pattern);

var hour = match.Groups[0].Value;
hour.Dump();
```

Prints `Ora01`.

If you want the hour part after `Ora` you'd have to group the digits :

```
var pattern = @"Ora(?<hour>[0-9]{2})";

var match = Regex.Match("/19/Ora01", pattern);

var hour = match.Groups["hour"].Value;
Console.WriteLine(hour);
```

This prints  :

```
01
```

You don't explain what kind of validation you want to perform, eg whether the slashes matter or not, whether `19` should be there and eg be treated as a year.

If you want to ensure the string follows this format *and* the first part is two-digit number, you could use eg `@"/(?<year>\d{2})/Ora(?<hour>\d{2})"` :

```
var pattern = @"/(?<year>\d{2})/Ora(?<hour>\d{2})";

var match = Regex.Match("/19/Ora01", pattern);

var hour = match.Groups["hour"].Value;
var year = match.Groups["year"].Value;
Console.WriteLine($"{year} {hour}");
```

This prints :

```
19 01
```

Only if the format is correct.

Comment: /19/Ora01, is a string coming from a database, 19 is not a Year but anyway i understand your answer and it is very helpful, i will mark it as the one that resolves my issue.

Comment: Can you help me with something else? the year can be with 1 or 2 digits so it can be `/0/Ora01` or it can be `/19/Ora01` so i have to change this: `\d{2}` but how.

Comment: @Erjon `\d{1,2}`

Answer (score 2):

What if you `Split()` by `/` if your string will be of the pattern `/19/Ora01`

```
var data = "/19/Ora01".Split("/", StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
```

Comment: Why? There are downsides to splitting. This creates 3 temporary strings, and needs extra parsing to actually extract the required value. There's no validation either

Answer (score 2):

This is what you want with Regex:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
  {
    string pattern = "\\/(.*?)\\/(.+)";
    string text = "/19/Ora01";
    Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
    string first = match.Groups[1].Value;
    string second = match.Groups[2].Value;

    Console.WriteLine(first);
    Console.WriteLine(second);

    Console.ReadLine();
  }
```

Consider also the answer provided by **Rahul**.

Comment: Thank you very much, your answer is very helpful to.

Answer (score 1):

In regular expression `^` means match from start of the string.

Just like `$` means match to end of the string.

Simply remove `^` from your pattern and your code should work.

Answer (score 1):

Regex is the best way to do this:

```
string pattern = "\\/(.*?)\\/(.+)";
string text = "/19/Ora01";
Match match = Regex.Match(text, pattern);
string first = match.Groups[1].Value;
string second = match.Groups[2].Value;

Console.WriteLine(first);
Console.WriteLine(second);
```

Also @Panagiotis Kanavos is probably the best answer and the most complete one.

Answer (score 0):

You could use string.Split for this, too. Might be faster then regex but depends on your needs.

With string.Split this could look like

```
var result = start.Substring(start.LastIndexOf("/") + 1);
```

If you want to use regex you have to remove the "^".
For easy testing and more information have a look at [regexr.com](https://regexr.com/)